# How to get Apache request thread handle number with PHP?

Tags: php, apache

How to get Apache request thread handle number of current executing PHP script in that script?

Platform: Windows, PHP<5.3

Comment: Please make it more clear so we can help you, are you trying to limit apache to serve K PHP files requests ?

Comment: Apache runs every request in thread. In windows every thread has a handle (ID) that identifies that thread. I want to know that thread handle of my currently running php script.

Comment: "Apache runs every request in thread" - yes and no. "In windows every thread has a handle (ID) that identifies that thread" Do you mean MSWindows? Never asked in post. "I want to know that thread handle of my currently running php script" - no way to get this without re-writing Apache. Why do you need this information?

Comment: If I know Thread Handle, I can get time CPU spent on this thread. I need this to correctly benchmark my PHP scripts CPU usage. Yes, MS Windows. I can get info (handle, cpu usage, etc.) about all threads of apache process, but I don`t know how to determinate which is my current PHP script thread.

Answer (score 2):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.getmypid.php

getmypid() should give you the handle id/ process id (pid)

Comment: It returns Process Handle of apache (httpd.exe), but I need Thread Handle of current Thread.